# Comparison of Parameter estimation using maximum likelihood and Maximum entropy.

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, functional-analysis, statistics, statistical-inference

I am not sure if the question is appropriate but I want to try my luck. One can estimate a parameter using maximum likelihood and we know it is optimal. On the other hand there are methods which uses maximum entropy to estimate parameter. Can someone compare these two methods? My intuition is that there are cases where both are equivalent. Is there a way to find when these two methods are equivalent and when not?